# restart process if process not finished after wait a second

Tags: vb.net

Can I restart the process if the process exceeds the time that I specify? For example I made a response header, if the process for response exceeds 10 second than the process restarted.

```
'time limit = 10 second
'if the process exceed time limit than restart the process

Dim request As System.Net.webrequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
request.Method = "HEAD"
Dim response As System.Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Does it matter whether they tried anything? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: As a timeout will throw [an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) which you can catch and examine to see if the timeout caused the exception, then you could contsruct some code to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using the `timeout` property. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) is the link to example code. This will allow you to catch a `WebException` exception.